# SharePoint: insert ASP code into login.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, fba

I have FBA (form_based_authentication) on my SP site, so thi first login site is login.aspx. 
Now there is following problem: users are coming from another site on the sharepoint. Herefor they using some kind of private key. The Public key is on the sharepoint webserver.

What I´m trying to do now is to modify the login.aspx with following example code I get from the creator of this mechanism, but I dont really know where to paste ist:

"<% String ct = Request.Params["ct"];
           String sp = Request.Params["sp"];
           ctf.TicketEvaluator e = new ctf.TicketEvaluator(Server.MapPath("keys"), 0);
           String payload = e.evaluateClassicTicketAsString(ct,sp,300000000,"lohn");
%>
        This was your payload: <%= payload %>
"

As a standalone .NET project it works fine, but I don´t have any idea how to put it into login.aspx.

Thanks a lot, 
fiuman007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own Login.aspx and then configure the web.config to use that page as the default login page for FBA. **Never change out of the box Sharepoint files** in the sharepoint 12-hive on the harddrive.

**ALWAYS** create your own custom version and point sharepoint to your customized page. this goes pretty much applies any time you think about modifying sharepoint 12-hive files.

**Don't take the easy way out, you will end up in maintenance hell.**

Comment: cool! 

P.S. Maybe it would be nice to update your post when everything's working :-D.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and very dirty method is to modify the login.aspx directly it's located on the SharePoint server(s) as:

```
"c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extension\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\login.aspx"
```

The quick and dirty method is to take a copy of the file above into a new subdirectory you make and make the changes here and then point to this new login page in the web.config(s)

The right solution is to make a feature with the web.config modification and put it into a solution with the login page. It'll get the same end result as method two but in a nice repeatable way which can put into Source Control

Comment: Thank you for response. I think I will copy login.aspx in login2.aspx and redirect in web.config on this.